# CollapsingToolbarLayout not work with ViewPager and WebView

Tags: android, android-studio, webview, material-design, android-support-library

I want to collapse toolbar in my activity when I scrolling WebView inside fragments (ViewPager). Using support library 22.2.1.
What am I doing wrong?
My activity code:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

                <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />
            </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/viewPager"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
              app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>
        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

My fragment code:

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Please, help.

Comment: where is your activity code ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Hiding/Showing the toolbar when fragment in the tabs is scrolled](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32069521/hiding-showing-the-toolbar-when-fragment-in-the-tabs-is-scrolled)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your ViewPager outside and below the AppBarLayout.