# Android: Hide/Show Toolbar while scrolling doesn't work

Tags: android, android-studio, android-appbarlayout, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

> I have this very simple layout:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/root"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ActionBarThemeOverlay">

        <!--<include layout="@layout/include_toolbar_actionbar" />-->

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/background"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

I add a `Fragment` with a standard `RecyclerView` into `fragment_container`. Unfortunately, the `Toolbar` is always hide, I can't understand why?

Thank you very much for your help guys!

Answer (score 0):

You could try this: [solution from similar question.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35477859/7836497)

Basically, you have to use `android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView` instead of `ScrollView` (in your fragment) and implement `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` inside your NestedScrollView xml.