# Toolbar is not hiding when i scroll content layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-fragments

```
    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/view_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/tab_bar" />

    <com.whl.handytabbar.HandyTabBar
        android:id="@+id/tab_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="@drawable/custom_shadow" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

Toolbar is inside an AppBarLayout which is probably inside your CoordinatorLayout then something like this should work.

```
AppBarLayout appBarLayout = (AppBarLayout)findViewById(R.id.appBar);
        appBarLayout.setExpanded(true, true);
```

Or to collapse toolbar then something like this should work

```
AppBarLayout appBarLayout = (AppBarLayout)findViewById(R.id.appBar);
        appBarLayout.setExpanded(false, true);
```

Comment: This is some documentation [https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/AppBarLayout.html#setExpanded(boolean)] for refrence.

Answer (score 0):

Follow this link you will get your answer here :

> [How to hide ToolBar when i scrolling content up in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35475884/how-to-hide-toolbar-when-i-scrolling-content-up-in-android)

Answer (score -1):

you need this `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` in your scroll view ase below:

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/rvToDoList"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
```

> we need to define an association between the AppBarLayout and the View
>   that will be scrolled. Add an app:layout_behavior to a RecyclerView or
>   any other View capable of nested scrolling such as NestedScrollView.
>   The support library contains a special string resource
>   @string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior that maps to
>   AppBarLayout.ScrollingViewBehavior, which is used to notify the
>   AppBarLayout when scroll events occur on this particular view. The
>   behavior must be established on the view that triggers the event.

You should take a look at [This Guide](http://guides.codepath.com/android/handling-scrolls-with-coordinatorlayout#overview)