# How to hide toolbar while scrolling efficientliy in relativeLayout?

Tags: android, scroll

I'm trying to hide the toolbar by making it `invisible` while scrolling and `visible` on stop,but it's not smooth .

Can anyone please suggest any better option for hiding toolbar elegantly while scrolling in `relativeLayout`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to hide ToolBar when i scrolling content up in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35475884/how-to-hide-toolbar-when-i-scrolling-content-up-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this is what you want, but this can make the system UI smooth show/hide when scrolling. See [Using Immersive Full-Screen Mode](https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/immersive.html)

Comment: Actually I've placed an edit text as search bar above the tabLayout so I wanna make it disappear while scrolling like fb app

Comment: @SrinivasNahak I think you can use Animation to make it fading to hide.

Answer (score -1):

You should use the Coordinator Layout as a parent in the xml file.
Coordinator Layout is designed to support this type of actions and "synchronise" this actions.

The is a good tutorial here: https://mzgreen.github.io/2015/06/23/How-to-hideshow-Toolbar-when-list-is-scrolling(part3)/