# Hide toolbar on scroll and keep it hidden unless on far top

Tags: android, layout, toolbar

I am using the following code to hide my toolbar when I scroll on my main activity and it works perfectly. Though, I want to change its behavior a little:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"   
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbarsdfs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"/>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
            android:scrollbars="horizontal"
            android:layout_below="@+id/toolbarsdfs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:tabTextColor="@android:color/white"
            app:tabSelectedTextColor="@android:color/white"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/white"
            app:tabIndicatorHeight="3dp" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tablayout"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

I want the toolbar to only show when the user reaches the far top of the view. I have a recyclerview that has a lot of rows. I want the user to be able to go up and down without being bothered by the toolbar unless he reaches the very top of the view. How can this be done? Thanks.

Edit: edited the code.

Comment: paste your `content_main` layout also

Comment: Sorry, I pasted the wrong snippet that I used. This is the right one.

Answer (score 0):

in `content_main.XML` use `android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView` instead of `ScrollView`.

also use `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` inside `android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView` like below.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textone"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="hello world"
                android:textSize="25dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            /// Add your other code here

            </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

reference from hear : [How to hide ToolBar when i scrolling content up in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35475884/how-to-hide-toolbar-when-i-scrolling-content-up-in-android)

Comment: I have posted the wrong snippet earlier, sorry. I have edited my original post with the right one.