# toolbar auto hide and show when scroll not working

Tags: java, android, xml, scroll, toolbar

I am so tried to do that. I have completed my android project and it also listed on google playstore. I want to make my app toolbar auto hide while scroll and auto show when scroll down/up.

> activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/colorBG"
    tools:context="net.gurujibd.ajkerkhobor.MainActivity">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark">

    </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>


    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

</LinearLayout>
```

it's my main activity. and i have a custom toolbar file.

> toolbar.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

and I am using fragment layout for tabbed activity.
it's my home activity.

> fragment_home.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context=".Home">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:background="@color/colorBG"
            android:weightSum="10"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textGrid"
                    android:text="Ajker Khobor"
                    android:textSize="34sp"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            </RelativeLayout>

            <GridLayout
                android:id="@+id/mainGrid"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="736dp"
                android:layout_weight="8"
                android:alignmentMode="alignMargins"
                android:columnCount="2"
                android:columnOrderPreserved="false"
                android:padding="14dp"
                android:rowCount="3">

                <!-- Row 1 -->

                <!-- Column 1 -->
                <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                    android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                    app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                    app:cardElevation="8dp">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                        android:layout_margin="16dp"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/prothomalo"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:src="@drawable/prothomalo" />

                    </LinearLayout>

                </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

                <!-- Column 2 -->
                <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                    android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                    app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                    app:cardElevation="8dp">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                        android:layout_margin="16dp"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/noyadigonto"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:src="@drawable/noyadigonto" />


                    </LinearLayout>

                </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


                <!-- Row 2 -->

                <!-- Column 1 -->
                <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                    android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                    app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                    app:cardElevation="8dp">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                        android:layout_margin="16dp"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/bangladeshprotidin"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:src="@drawable/bangladeshprotidin" />

                    </LinearLayout>

                </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

                <!-- Column 2 -->
                <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                    android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                    app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                    app:cardElevation="8dp">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                        android:layout_margin="16dp"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/inclub"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:src="@drawable/inclub" />


                    </LinearLayout>

                </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


                <!-- Row 2 -->

                <!-- Column 1 -->
                <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                    android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                    app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                    app:cardElevation="8dp">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                        android:layout_margin="16dp"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/manobkontho"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:src="@drawable/manobkontho" />


                    </LinearLayout>

                </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

                <!-- Column 2 -->
                <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                    android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                    app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                    app:cardElevation="8dp">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                        android:layout_margin="16dp"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/ittefaq"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:src="@drawable/ittefaq" />

                    </LinearLayout>

                </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

                <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                    android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                    app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                    app:cardElevation="8dp">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                        android:layout_margin="16dp"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/jugantor"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:src="@drawable/jugantor" />

                    </LinearLayout>

                </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

                <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                    android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                    app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                    app:cardElevation="8dp">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                        android:layout_margin="16dp"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/somoynews"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:src="@drawable/somoynews" />

                    </LinearLayout>

                </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

                <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                    android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                    app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                    app:cardElevation="8dp">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                        android:layout_margin="16dp"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/amadersomoy"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:src="@drawable/amadersomoy" />

                    </LinearLayout>

                </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

                <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                    android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                    app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                    app:cardElevation="8dp">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                        android:layout_margin="16dp"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/manobjomin"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:src="@drawable/manobjomin" />

                    </LinearLayout>

                </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

                <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                    android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                    app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                    app:cardElevation="8dp">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                        android:layout_margin="16dp"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/kalerkontho"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:src="@drawable/kalerkontho" />

                    </LinearLayout>

                </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

                <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                    android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                    app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                    app:cardElevation="8dp">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                        android:layout_margin="16dp"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/bonikbarta"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:src="@drawable/bonikbarta" />

                    </LinearLayout>

                </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

                <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                    android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                    app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                    app:cardElevation="8dp">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                        android:layout_margin="16dp"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/bbcbangla"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:src="@drawable/bbcbangla" />

                    </LinearLayout>

                </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

                <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                    android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                    app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                    app:cardElevation="8dp">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                        android:layout_margin="16dp"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/songbad"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:src="@drawable/songbad" />

                    </LinearLayout>

                </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

                <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                    android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                    app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                    app:cardElevation="8dp">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                        android:layout_margin="16dp"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/jonokontho"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:src="@drawable/jonokontho" />

                    </LinearLayout>

                </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

                <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                    android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                    app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                    app:cardElevation="8dp">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                        android:layout_margin="16dp"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/vorerkagoj"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:src="@drawable/vorerkagoj" />

                    </LinearLayout>

                </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            </GridLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

</FrameLayout>
```

please help me to solve this problem. advanced thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to hide ToolBar when i scrolling content up in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35475884/how-to-hide-toolbar-when-i-scrolling-content-up-in-android)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Toolbar scrolling behavior was introduced in **Material Design** and implemented along [CoordinatorLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/CoordinatorLayout). To use this feature you must use `CoordinatorLayout` along `Appbar` in your app layout.

For more info check this tutorial:
https://guides.codepath.com/android/handling-scrolls-with-coordinatorlayout

For example in your code:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorBG"
    tools:context="net.gurujibd.ajkerkhobor.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <include
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            layout="@layout/toolbar"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll"/>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
            app:tabMode="fixed"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll"/>
     </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

and don't forget to change your `scrollView` to `NestedScrollView`:

```
<FrameLayout>
    <ScrollView>
        <Your Content .../>
    </ScrollView>
</FrameLayout>
```

, changes to:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
    <Your Content .../>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: i was read this type of instructions. but i can't do that with my code. can you please edit my code and post it an Answer for me? i can't understand where i need to put CoordinatorLayout. edit my code and past it here. thanks

Comment: not working... when i'm scrolling the toolbar not effected anything. please help.

Comment: can i need to do anything on java file?

Comment: thanks. it working by adding app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" in toolbar... but one more problems. while i'm scrolling it was hiding toolbar withe viewpager. i want to show viwepager alwasy, only hide toolbar. how to do that?

Comment: many many thanks bro... now all problem is solved. thanks for your help.

Comment: urw, try experiment with the tutorial to test other scrolling behavior!