# Transparent Toolbar over RecyclerView is not hidding when scrolling

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-coordinatorlayout, android-appbarlayout

I've some troubles trying to hide toolbar when user scrolls over the recyclerView.

The toolbar is transparent and is over the recyclerView (through FrameLayout). I've searched a lot but I haven't found any solution to solve this incorrect behaviour.

Currently, I've this xml:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:statusBarBackground="@android:color/transparent">


    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <include layout="@layout/toolbar_activity" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rv"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    </FrameLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

With this code, the toolbar is fixed at the top and it's not affected by ***app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"***. I've tried moving that attribute to the FrameLayout but in this case, the recyclerview is below the toolbar, not behind it.

Any idea of how can I solve this? I'm going crazy...

Comment: why do you need `Framelayout`? use `RecyclerView` direclty

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35477859/8475893

Comment: Removing the FrameLayout, the recyclerview appears below the Toolbar

Answer (score 0):

set property
`app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"`
to child view of android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout

Comment: just make sure that you have added android design dependency, working for me   
`implementation "com.android.support:design:28.0.0"`

Comment: Sure, the dependency is added. Are you showing the recyclerview behind the toolbar? Or the recyclerview is below toolbar?

Comment: In my case, the recyclerview should be behind the toolbar =( 
Thanks for your help anyway!

Comment: I guess you want parallax effect if so this link might helpful for you **[Parallax-Recycleview](https://github.com/kanytu/android-parallax-recyclerview)**

Answer (score 0):

> Create a custom class and then  extend RecyclerView.OnScrollListener

```
public class ScrollListener extends RecyclerView.OnScrollListener {
    public ScrollListener() {
    }

    public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
        switch (newState) {
            case RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE:
                System.out.println("The RecyclerView is not scrolling");
                break;
            case RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_DRAGGING:
                System.out.println("Scrolling now");
                break;
            case RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_SETTLING:
                System.out.println("Scroll Settling");
                break;

        }

    }

    public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {

        if (dy > 0) {
            //scrolling downwards: hide/show toolbar 
            System.out.println("Scrolled Downwards");
        } else if (dy < 0) {
            //scrolling downwards: hide/show  toolbar 
        }
    }
}
```

> Attach listener to recycler view

```
 mRecyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new ScrollListener());
```

Comment: By this way, the recyclerview is below Toolbar. I would like that the recycler was behind the toolbar

Comment: Please give a try to `CollapsingToolbarLayout`

Comment: Yes, I've tried with collapsingToolbarLayout too, but I haven't achieve it either

Answer (score 0):

Add these scroll flags to child of your app bar layout

`app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap"`