# layout behavior not working in frame layout

Tags: android, android-layout

i am trying to make my toolbar hide/show while content is scrolling,When i injecting it into the FrameLayout container and it doesn't work, here is my appbar layout:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".BaseActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/tool_bar_bg"
        app:elevation="0dp"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_actionbar"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>



        <!-- My scrolling content -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>



    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

and my SecondActivity layout

```
   <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingRight="20dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textone"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="@string/content"
            android:textSize="25dp" />


    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

and this is my java code to infliate activity layout:

```
    public class FirstActivity extends BaseActivity {   
       @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            //inflate your activity layout here!
            @SuppressLint("InflateParams")
            View contentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_user, null, false);
            drawer.addView(contentView, 0);
}
```

when i scrolling it doesn't working  and also i checked in SecondActivity with `RelativeLayout,LinearLayout` as well but its not hiding.

Comment: go for this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35475884/how-to-hide-toolbar-when-i-scrolling-content-up-in-android, may it helps you

Comment: i tried this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35475884/how-to-hide-toolbar-when-i-scrolling-content-up-in-android ,but not working

Comment: Other solution is to put Toolbar layout in nested scroolview also..if you want to scroll toolbar also

Comment: i put toolbar layout in nested scroll view but app is crashed.

Comment: show me your code please..and also show the crash log you face

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem with layout inflater i have changed my layout inflater:

```
FrameLayout container = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.content_frame);
        View inflatedLayout= getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_user, null, false);
        container.addView(inflatedLayout);
```

Answer (score 1):

please surround the items you want to hide/show during scroll using `android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout`

read more about the subject here, 
[collapsing-toolbar-layout](https://material.io/develop/android/components/collapsing-toolbar-layout/)