# Need to use the BottomSheetBehavior and ScrollingViewBehavior for a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, android-toolbar, bottom-sheet

I have a Main Activity with a Fragment inside it. The layout of the main activity is having the FrameLayout to hold the fragment. I have set the ScrollingViewBehavior to the Framelayout of main activity, inorder to achieve the auto hide property of toolbar on scrolling. The layout of the Fragment is having a NestedScrollView with the BottomSheetBehavior added to it. Toolbar is seem to be fixed and not working as expected on scrolling. Guess, it might be due to the **app:layout_behavior** set to both the main layout and fragment layout.

Could someone help me in fixing this?

Answer (score 0):

**Set this flag to your ToolBar.**

```
 app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
```

[How to hide ToolBar when i scrolling content up in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35475884/how-to-hide-toolbar-when-i-scrolling-content-up-in-android)

it may help you

Answer (score 0):

Moved the bottom sheet also to the main activity's layout, solved the issue.