# How do I animate Views in Toolbar when user scrolls?

Tags: android, animation, android-animation, objectanimator

I am trying to put some animation in my application. Please find the photo attached to get animation idea.

[image: Toolbar is cart icon rectangle and search_layout is below that.]

I have used CoordinatorLayout. My search layout and toolbar is hosted inside AppBarLayout/CollapsingToolbarLayout. Below that is my NestedScrollView hosting fragment.

I am able to hide search layout when user scrolls using scroll flags. I am trying to implement a CoordinatorLayout.Behavior which will start moving the cart icon to the left and start search icon to scale from 0 to 1; as soon as the user scrolls and search layout starts to hide. When search layout is fully hidden, I want to show toolbar like in second screen. And it will come back to original state as shown in first screen when user scrolls down and search layout starts to show up by slowly moving cart to right and scaling down search icon.

Initially I have made the search icon on toolbar as hidden and cart icon & search icon are inside a linearlayout.

Please find my xml activity_home_page.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.example.ui.customviews.CustomDrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/ab_app_bar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

            <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="131dp"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/ll_search_layout"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="75dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:visibility="visible"
                    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|snap">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/ll_search_box"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="51dp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/dimen_12_dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/dimen_8_dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/dimen_8_dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dimen_12_dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/round_corner_layout_white"
                        android:elevation="@dimen/dimen_5_dp"
                        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">

                        <EditText
                            android:id="@+id/et_search"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/dimen_15_dp"
                            android:layout_weight="80"
                            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                            android:hint="Search for Products"
                            android:padding="@dimen/dimen_5_dp"
                            android:textColor="@color/black"
                            android:textColorHint="@color/hint_text_color"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/dimen_text_16_sp" />

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/iv_search_icon"
                            android:layout_width="@dimen/dimen_22_dp"
                            android:layout_height="@dimen/dimen_24_dp"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/dimen_17_dp"
                            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/dimen_20_dp"
                            android:src="@drawable/ic_search_grey" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                </LinearLayout>

                <include
                    layout="@layout/layout_primary_toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/toolbar_primary_height"
                    android:layout_gravity="top"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="pin"/>

            </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:background="@color/askme_blue"
            app:layout_behavior="com.GetIt.animation.SearchLayoutBehavior"/>

        <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/container"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

        </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer"
        android:name="com.example.ui.fragment.SideMenuFragment"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start" />
</com.example.ui.customviews.CustomDrawerLayout>
```

My xml for layout_primary_toolbar.xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/toolbar_primary_height"
    android:background="@color/askme_blue"
    app:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
    app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_drawer_menu"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/dimen_22_dp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/dimen_22_dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/dimen_16_dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/dimen_15_dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_drawer_menu" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_back_btn"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/dimen_22_dp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/dimen_20_dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/dimen_16_dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/dimen_15_dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_back_button"
            android:visibility="gone"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ll_location"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center">

            <com.GetIt.ui.customviews.TextViewRRegular
                android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Delhi"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:visibility="visible" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/toolbar_location_change"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_edit_location"
                android:visibility="gone"/>
        </LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/dimen_16_dp">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/rl_cart_count"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/dimen_40_dp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/dimen_40_dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="@dimen/dimen_25_dp"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/dimen_24_dp"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:clickable="false"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                android:scaleType="center"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_cart" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_cart_count"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/dimen_17_dp"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/dimen_17_dp"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/dimen_3_dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dimen_3_dp"
                android:background="@drawable/cart_count_background_circle"
                android:elevation="@dimen/dimen_5_dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="@dimen/dimen_text_10_sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:visibility="visible" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/rl_search"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/dimen_40_dp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/dimen_40_dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/rl_cart_count">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv_search"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/dimen_24_dp"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/dimen_24_dp"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_search" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

I am stuck on this for last 7 hours. I am new to android animation.

Initially I am hiding rl_search (search box) programmatically. I want that when ll_search_layout scrolls up (beneath the toolbar), rl_cart should move to left (which is its original position had rl_search not been made hidden) and rl_search should scale from 0 to 1.

I have used ObjectAnimator with LinearInterpolator but its not working at all.

Any suggestions how to achieve this?

P.S. - I can post the code if you guys need that for reference.

Thanks

Answer (score 26, accepted):

After trying myself for over 2 days, finally I am able to do the animation. I am posting this answer for others if they also wants to do something like that.

I have not used animation utility of android but a hack to increase and decrease padding and scaling up and down the search icon.

This is my behaviour class

```
public class SearchLayoutBehavior extends CoordinatorLayout.Behavior<ImageView> {

    Context mContext;

    private static final int DIRECTION_UP = 1;
    private static final int DIRECTION_DOWN = -1;
    private static final int CART_PADDING_LOWER_LIMIT = 0;
    private static int CART_PADDING_UPPER_LIMIT;
    private static final float SEARCH_SCALING_LOWER_LIMIT = 0.0f;
    private static final float SEARCH_SCALING_UPPER_LIMIT = 1.0f;
    private float CART_PADDING_MULTIPLICATION_FACTOR;
    private float SEARCH_SCALE_MULTIPLICATION_FACTOR;

    RelativeLayout mRlSearch, mRlParentCart;
    Toolbar mToolbar;
    LinearLayout mLlSearchLayout;

    boolean mIsSetupDone = false;
    int mScrollingDirection, mPrevDiff1, mPrevDiff2;

    public SearchLayoutBehavior() {
        super();
    }

    public SearchLayoutBehavior(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean layoutDependsOn(CoordinatorLayout parent, ImageView child, View dependency) {
        return (dependency.getId() == R.id.ab_app_bar);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDependentViewChanged(CoordinatorLayout parent, ImageView child, View dependency) {
        mRlParentCart = (RelativeLayout) dependency.findViewById(R.id.rl_parent_cart_count);
        mRlSearch = (RelativeLayout) dependency.findViewById(R.id.rl_search);
        mToolbar = (Toolbar) dependency.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        mLlSearchLayout = (LinearLayout) dependency.findViewById(R.id.ll_search_layout);

        int searchLayoutBottom = mLlSearchLayout.getBottom();
        int searchLayoutTop = mLlSearchLayout.getTop();
        int toolbarBottom = mToolbar.getBottom();

        int diff1 = searchLayoutBottom - toolbarBottom;
        int diff2 = searchLayoutTop - toolbarBottom;

        if (!mIsSetupDone) {
            CART_PADDING_UPPER_LIMIT = mContext.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.cart_animation_move_left);
            CART_PADDING_MULTIPLICATION_FACTOR = (float) CART_PADDING_UPPER_LIMIT / diff1;
            SEARCH_SCALE_MULTIPLICATION_FACTOR = (float) 1 / diff1;
            mPrevDiff1 = diff1;
            mPrevDiff2 = -diff1;
            mIsSetupDone = true;
        }

        if (mScrollingDirection == DIRECTION_UP && mPrevDiff1 >= diff1) {
            moveCart(mRlParentCart, mPrevDiff1 - diff1, true);
            mPrevDiff1 = diff1;
        } else if (mScrollingDirection == DIRECTION_DOWN && mPrevDiff2 <= diff2) {
            moveCart(mRlParentCart, diff2 - mPrevDiff2, false);
            mPrevDiff2 = diff2;
        }

        if (diff2 == 0) {
            mPrevDiff1 = diff1;
            mPrevDiff2 = -diff1;
        }

        return true;
    }

    private void moveCart(final View view, float by, boolean doMoveLeft) {
        int paddingRight = view.getPaddingRight();
        float scaleX = mRlSearch.getScaleX();
        float scaleY = mRlSearch.getScaleY();

        if (doMoveLeft) {
            paddingRight += (int) (by * CART_PADDING_MULTIPLICATION_FACTOR);
            if (paddingRight >= CART_PADDING_UPPER_LIMIT) {
                view.setPadding(0, 0, CART_PADDING_UPPER_LIMIT, 0);
            } else {
                view.setPadding(0, 0, paddingRight, 0);
            }

            scaleX += by * SEARCH_SCALE_MULTIPLICATION_FACTOR;
            scaleY += by * SEARCH_SCALE_MULTIPLICATION_FACTOR;
            if (Float.compare(scaleX, SEARCH_SCALING_UPPER_LIMIT) >= 0) {
                mRlSearch.setScaleX(SEARCH_SCALING_UPPER_LIMIT);
            } else {
                mRlSearch.setScaleX(scaleX);
            }

            if (Float.compare(scaleY, SEARCH_SCALING_UPPER_LIMIT) >= 0) {
                mRlSearch.setScaleY(SEARCH_SCALING_UPPER_LIMIT);
            } else {
                mRlSearch.setScaleY(scaleY);
            }

        } else {
            paddingRight -= (int) (by * CART_PADDING_MULTIPLICATION_FACTOR);
            if (paddingRight <= CART_PADDING_LOWER_LIMIT) {
                view.setPadding(0, 0, CART_PADDING_LOWER_LIMIT, 0);
            } else {
                view.setPadding(0, 0, paddingRight, 0);
            }

            scaleX -= by * SEARCH_SCALE_MULTIPLICATION_FACTOR;
            scaleY -= by * SEARCH_SCALE_MULTIPLICATION_FACTOR;

            if (Float.compare(scaleX, SEARCH_SCALING_LOWER_LIMIT) == -1) {
                mRlSearch.setScaleX(SEARCH_SCALING_LOWER_LIMIT);
            } else {
                mRlSearch.setScaleX(scaleX);
            }

            if (Float.compare(scaleY, SEARCH_SCALING_LOWER_LIMIT) == -1) {
                mRlSearch.setScaleY(SEARCH_SCALING_LOWER_LIMIT);
            } else {
                mRlSearch.setScaleY(scaleY);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onNestedPreScroll(CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout, ImageView child, View target, int dx, int dy, int[] consumed) {
        //Determine direction changes here
        if (dy > 0 && mScrollingDirection != DIRECTION_UP) {
            mScrollingDirection = DIRECTION_UP;
        } else if (dy < 0 && mScrollingDirection != DIRECTION_DOWN) {
            mScrollingDirection = DIRECTION_DOWN;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onStartNestedScroll(CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout, ImageView child, View directTargetChild, View target, int nestedScrollAxes) {
        return (nestedScrollAxes & ViewCompat.SCROLL_AXIS_VERTICAL) != 0;
    }

}
```

This is my xml which uses coordinator layout. When the search layout moves up, cart moves to left and search icon scales up.

```
<com.example.ui.customviews.CustomDrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/ab_app_bar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

            <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="131dp"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/ll_search_layout"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="75dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:visibility="visible"
                    android:background="@drawable/search_layout_twin_background"
                    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|snap">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/ll_search_box"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="51dp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/dimen_12_dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/dimen_8_dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/dimen_8_dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dimen_12_dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/round_corner_layout_white"
                        android:elevation="@dimen/dimen_5_dp"
                        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">

                        <EditText
                            android:id="@+id/et_search"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/dimen_15_dp"
                            android:layout_weight="80"
                            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                            android:hint="Search for Products"
                            android:padding="@dimen/dimen_5_dp"
                            android:textColor="@color/black"
                            android:textColorHint="@color/hint_text_color"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/dimen_text_16_sp" />

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/iv_search_icon"
                            android:layout_width="@dimen/dimen_22_dp"
                            android:layout_height="@dimen/dimen_24_dp"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/dimen_17_dp"
                            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/dimen_20_dp"
                            android:src="@drawable/ic_search_grey" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                </LinearLayout>

                <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/toolbar_primary_height"
    android:background="@color/askme_blue"
    app:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
    app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv_drawer_menu"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/dimen_22_dp"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/dimen_22_dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/dimen_16_dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/dimen_15_dp"
                android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_drawer_menu" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv_back_btn"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/dimen_22_dp"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/dimen_20_dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/dimen_16_dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/dimen_15_dp"
                android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_back_button"
                android:visibility="gone" />
        </FrameLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ll_location"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="Delhi"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:visibility="visible" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/toolbar_location_change"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/dimen_3_dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dimen_4_dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_edit_location"
                android:visibility="visible" />
        </LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="@dimen/dimen_100_dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/dimen_16_dp"
        android:gravity="right">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/rl_search"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/dimen_40_dp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/dimen_40_dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|right"
            android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"
            android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv_search"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/dimen_24_dp"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/dimen_24_dp"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_search" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/rl_parent_cart_count"
            android:layout_width="94dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|right"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:paddingRight="54dp">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/rl_cart_count"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/dimen_40_dp"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/dimen_40_dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|right"
                android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/dimen_25_dp"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/dimen_24_dp"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:clickable="false"
                    android:focusable="false"
                    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                    android:scaleType="center"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_cart" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_cart_count"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/dimen_17_dp"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/dimen_17_dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/dimen_3_dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dimen_3_dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/cart_count_background_circle"
                    android:elevation="@dimen/dimen_5_dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/dimen_text_10_sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:visibility="visible" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </FrameLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

            </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:background="@color/askme_blue"
            app:layout_behavior="com.GetIt.animation.SearchLayoutBehavior"/>

        <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/container"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

        </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer"
        android:name="com.example.ui.fragment.SideMenuFragment"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start" />
</com.example.ui.customviews.CustomDrawerLayout>
```

This is how it will look like.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Design your layout like below with `CoordinatorLayout` and `AppBarLayout` and add a `Toolbar` inside it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/coordinatorlayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".dashboard.DashboardActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbarlayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <include
            layout="@layout/toolbar_default"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            app:tabMaxWidth="0dp"
            app:tabIndicatorHeight="4dp"
            app:tabMode="fixed"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/white"
            android:background="@color/AppPrimary"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_dashboard" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

And in your dashboard content's layout res define a layout behavior for your content like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context=".dashboard.DashboardActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_dashboard">


    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

It's a bit old fashion but you can check my solution without coorinator layout from the link below:
[Android Toolbar + Tab Layout + Drawer, Hide toolbar when scrolling and take TabLayout to the top](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33999783/android-toolbar-tab-layout-drawer-hide-toolbar-when-scrolling-and-take-tabl/34181195#34181195)

Good Luck.

Comment: How can I do animation in this. I want the animation rest everything is working fine.

Comment: you can check my other solution from link. it'll help you.

Comment: Thanks man. Finally I did it over the weekend. It does not use Animator class but it works. I posted my answer here with gif.