# Action bar with cordinator layout doesn't "snap" to being fully hidden or fully revealed on partial change android

Tags: android, androiddesignsupport

I have used the coordinator layout to acheive the bar collapsing the action bar.
Now my problem is that I scroll just small enough to hide action bar partially the below stays there. 
What I want is that even if I leave it hidden partially; it (the bar below with few button) should merge with action bar.**(Similar to Whatsapp)**
My code is:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <include
                android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
                layout="@layout/pmp_toolbar_2" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/pmp_list"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scrollbars="vertical"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

The action bar when scrolled a bit looks like:
[image]

And my build.gradle file is

```
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'
```

**UPDATE:**
See abhishek's comment; this issue is resolved in library update

Comment: What do you mean by merging? If you want it to dissapear, use fullscreen. Otherwise, let it there and don't make action bar scrollable.

Comment: @mrek actually what the bar you are seeing below (with icons) collapses with action bar

Comment: I am sorry but I don't understand what do you mean exactly.

Comment: @mrek the problem is that I want the action bar behavior exactly as that of whatsapp. You try to leave the action bar at this stage in whatsapp; it wont stay. It will either move up or move down

Comment: do you think [this](https://mzgreen.github.io/2015/06/23/How-to-hideshow-Toolbar-when-list-is-scrolling(part3)/) behaviour? I think it is because of `include` branch which overrides the usual behavior. Check that tutorial above - it could be helpful.

Comment: @mrek the problem is the same as that of the first comment in the link you provided

Comment: @AnswerDroid I may have a workaround for you. Please see my answer.

Comment: This feature has been added in `23.1.0` version of support library. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31839173/how-to-make-the-toolbar-snap-into-view-or-out-of-view-when-using-google-design-l/33163714#33163714

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a [known issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=175506&can=1&q=is%3Astarred&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars) with `Toolbar` in the Android Design Support Library. It is marked as "FutureRelease" in the Android issue tracker since 9th September, which means the fix should be out soon. **Note, the fix has *not* been released yet.**

**EDIT**: if you really want to fix this yourself now, there is a workaround posted in this other question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32089807/504611 (found this link through the bug report itself).

**LATEST EDIT (RESOLVED):**
This is fixed in support library v23.1.0. See
[How to make the Toolbar snap into view or out of view when using Google Design Library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31839173/how-to-make-the-toolbar-snap-into-view-or-out-of-view-when-using-google-design-l/33163714#33163714)

Comment: Thanks for understanding the problem itself first of all

Comment: Next time somebody says it's a bug, ask for a link to the Android bug report, you can generally find workarounds posted by other people there :)

Answer (score 2):

I'm using following layout to achieve scroll effect like whatsapp

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_done" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: I have done similar thing , but I will check and see if it works

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question I guess.. I dont have challenge in getting this layout- the challenge is that  I am unable to get that snap effect

Comment: @AnswerDroid what snap effect u want to achieve ??

Comment: just try to scroll the whatsapp screen that has tabs a bit.. if you will leave it either it will merge with toolbar fully or will not merge at all . you will not be able to get the view( as shown in image above) if you stop scrolling.That is the snap effect I am talking about

Comment: Okay I got your point. It doesn't stop at that position where you left scrolling. Let me check the code again.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="192dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapseToolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="80dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="30dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:title="Custom Layout">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@drawable/bridge"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="1.5"/>


            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"/>

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:backgroundTint="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
        app:elevation="10dp"
        android:translationZ="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        app:layout_anchor="@+id/appBar"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"
        app:borderWidth="0dp"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:src="@drawable/plus" />
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/uid"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: I dont have challenge in getting this layout- the challenge is that I am unable to get that snap effect

Comment: just try to scroll the whatsapp screen that has tabs a bit.. if you will leave it either it will merge with toolbar fully or will not merge at all . you will not be able to get the view( as shown in image above) if you stop scrolling. am i clear?